# creating and checking of invertible matrix inside a class

Tags: python-3.x, class, matrix

I have a task to encrypt a dataset X. I created a class that creates a matrix and then uses it for multiplying. But also I'd like to check invertibility of this matrix. So my code is

```
class Preparer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):


def fit(self, X, y=None, random_state=None):
    if random_state:
        np.random.seed(random_state)
        
    X_d = X.shape[1]
    Z = np.random.normal(size=(X_d, X_d))
    
    
    self.Z = Z
    self.X = X
    return self

def check(self):
    ch = self.Z
    Z_rev = np.linalg.inv(ch)
    if np.allclose(np.dot(ch, Z_rev), np.eye(ch.shape[0])) is True:
        ans = "Correct, it's alive"
    else:
        ans = "Incorrect"
    return ans

def transform(self, X, y=None):  
    return X.dot(self.Z)
```

Then I use it but I have an error

```
X_new = Preparer().fit_transform(X, random_state=12345)
print(Preparer().check())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-970f16a02444> in <module>
      1 X_new = Preparer().fit_transform(X, random_state=12345)
----> 2 check_m = Preparer().check()
      3 print(Preparer().check())
      4 display(X.shape, X_new.shape)

<ipython-input-48-325b53b325ec> in check(self, y)
     15 
     16     def check(self, y=None):
---> 17         ch = self.Z
     18         Z_rev = np.linalg.inv(ch)
     19         if np.allclose(np.dot(ch, Z_rev), np.eye(ch.shape[0])) is True:

AttributeError: 'Preparer' object has no attribute 'Z'
```

So could you tell me how I can realize a check operation? I'm just starting to learn classes and I can't create a right request inside the class.

Comment: ```self.Z``` is not defined when you call Preparer.check() because it's defined (afaik) in ```fit_transform()``` which you don't call.  You need to initialize self.Z  either in Preparer class' constructor or set it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the class variables inside `__init__` method.
For more details check [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__init__-in-python/).

Comment: Thanks for answers! I evade __init__ and solved this problem by copy creation